# Android GridView Place Half items on Left and Half on Right

Tags: java, android, gridview

Suppose we have 6 items, is there any possibility or way to place 3 items on left side of the row and 3 items on right side of the row in grid view and eventually we have a space in between them.

Actually I tried to give dynamic horizontal spacing after from the adapter but it didn't help me out. The picture is attached

[image]

```
    package com.nxd.cap.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.nxd.cap.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    int[] images = new int[]{R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4,
            R.drawable.image5, R.drawable.image6, R.drawable.image7, R.drawable.image8,
            R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2};

    public GalleryAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return images[i];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
                context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, null);

            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
//        Picasso.with(context).load(images[i]).into(viewHolder.image);

        GridView gridView = (GridView)viewGroup;
        if (i == images.length/2) {
            gridView.setHorizontalSpacing(100);
        }

        viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(images[i]);

        return view;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible if you show us what you tried instead of asking first

Comment: nope still didn't get your question. elaborate further

Comment: show us your code so that we know what have you done so far.

Comment: this may help you, https://github.com/yarolegovich/DiscreteScrollView

Answer (score 0):

when you used gridView you can set number of column.if need only two column left and right set below code.

```
   gridView.setNumColumns(2);
```